# PIL Module and 500 Server Error when running foursquare connected app

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, foursquare

I am getting the following errors even though I downloaded and installed PIL in for my foursquare connected app. Need some help please.

```
    Could not initialize images API
    500 Server Error
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get an Error 500, always look in the logs.

My guess is you haven't configured third party libraries

Have a read of "Configuring Libraries" in the 2.7 runtime  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27#Configuring_Libraries

and have a look at the list of Third party libraries already provided https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

PIL only needs to be installed for dev server functionality.

Other third party libraries that are not in the list, need to be copied or linked into your project. Their code needs to be deployed with your application, and can't be if they are installed as part of your python environment.

Oh, you should also search SO for answers, this question comes up a lot.

Comment: Ok, after I configure the libraries what do I save them as? Also, the third party libraries do I just install PIL from that link and put in the the home folder of my app? I'm sorry I'm sort of new to Python.

Comment: JUst install PIL normally (for python) , and then configure the library in app.yaml.   PIL you do not need to deploy.  Other libraries that are not in the list of 2.7 included libs, must be copied or symlinked into your application directory.